# Unit testing connected higher-order components in React/Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, mocha.js, enzyme

In normal `connect`ed React components, in order to make unit testing easier, I've seen the pattern of [`export`ing the base component, while `export default`ing the connected component](https://hackernoon.com/unit-testing-redux-connected-components-692fa3c4441c). It works well for simple tests that handle the actual functionality of the component without getting cluttered with redux stores and router mocking.

I'm looking for an analog for higher-order components. For instance, given a trivial higher-order component:

```
export default function exampleHoc(Wrapped) {
  const ExampleHoc = props => (
    <Wrapped {...props.reduxStore} hoc={true} />
  );

  return connect(
    state => ({
      reduxStore: state.example.reduxStore,
    }))(ExampleHoc);
}
```

I'd like to verify that `props.hoc === true` in a unit test, without having to wire up the other higher-order components that `<ExampleHoc>` strings along.

My best design is passing along a flag:

```
export default function exampleHoc(Wrapped, exportUnconnectedForTest) {
  const ExampleHoc = props => (
    <Wrapped {...props.reduxStore} hoc={true} />
  );

  if (exportUnconnectedForTest) {
    return ExampleHoc;
  }

  return connect(
    state => ({
      reduxStore: state.example.reduxStore,
    }))(ExampleHoc);
}
```

This makes it easy to test

```
const DummyComponent = () => <div />;
const Sut = exampleHoc(DummyComponent, true);

...

test('props value should be passed', () => {
  const sut = shallow(<Sut />);
  const childProps = sut.find(DummyComponent).props();
  expect(sut.childProps.hoc).to.equal(true);
});
```

while still happily passing along the wrapped output to any regular callers of the method.

It works, but it seems clunky to me. Is there a better/established pattern for delivering the unwrapped interior of a higher-order component?

Comment: You need to test exampleHoc ? I believe you don't need to make DummyComponent

Comment: As `exampleHoc` is a method, it requires a target to be applied to. `DummyComponent` provides that, so that its given `props` can be inspected.

Comment: `shallow(<Sut.WrappedComponent />).div();` Can you try this without making `DummyComp` ? Let me know what issue you get in while running test